# How to target child element in css within a div?

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` parent element with the id="workflow". For the .active styling, may I know how to target the li element within it in the html? I have no issue with the first few blocks of the css with div#workflow.

```
        div#workflow li {
            width: 5em;
            height: 5em;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 5em;
            border-radius: 5em;
            background: dodgerblue;
            margin: 0 1.8em;
            display: inline-block;
            color: white;
            position: relative;
        }

        div#workflow li::before {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            top: 2.5em;
            left: -4em;
            width: 4em;
            height: .2em;
            background: dodgerblue;
            z-index: 1;
        }

        div#workflow li:first-child::before {
            display: none;
        }

        .active {
          background: dodgerblue;
        }

        .active ~ li {
          background: lightblue;
        }

        .active ~ li::before {
          background: lightblue;
        }


   <div id="workflow">
            <ul style="font-size:12px;">
              <li >Create</li>
              <li>Submitted</li>
              <li>In Process</li>
              <li class="active">Complete</li>
              <li>Closed</li>
            </ul> 
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#workflow li {
      #your normal style
    }

#workflow li.active {
      #your active style
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below selector.

```
#workflow > li {
      #your styling here
    }
```

Comment: This won't work since the li is not directly under the id workflow.

If you want to use the direct child selector make you include the ul.
#workflow > ul > li.active {}

Answer (score 1):

Sure, lets say you only want to target "submitted"

Simply do it like this:

```
#workflow > ul ::nth-child(2) {}
```

See here. I made only "submitted" red text.

```css
        div#workflow li {
            width: 5em;
            height: 5em;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 5em;
            border-radius: 5em;
            background: dodgerblue;
            margin: 0 1.8em;
            display: inline-block;
            color: white;
            position: relative;
        }

        div#workflow li::before {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            top: 2.5em;
            left: -4em;
            width: 4em;
            height: .2em;
            background: dodgerblue;
            z-index: 1;
        }

        div#workflow li:first-child::before {
            display: none;
        }

        .active {
          background: dodgerblue;
        }

        .active ~ li {
          background: lightblue;
        }

        .active ~ li::before {
          background: lightblue;
        }
        
        #workflow > ul :nth-child(2) {
          color: red;
        }
```

```html
   <div id="workflow">
            <ul style="font-size:12px;">
              <li >Create</li>
              <li>Submitted</li>
              <li>In Process</li>
              <li class="active">Complete</li>
              <li>Closed</li>
            </ul> 
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The below selector will work:

```
div#workflow > ul > li.active {
  /* Styling */
}
```